# How to send automatic email notification to user two days before expiry date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In SharePoint 2007 document library I want to send automatic email notification to user two days before expiry date.
After expiry date document will remain in the library.
Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create workflow in SharePoint designer. During creation of an item the workflow starts and waits until execution date. If expiry date can be changed you need another action which cancels old workflow (with old date) and starts new one (with need date).

[Here](http://markeev.com/Articles/item-expiration-reminders-in-sharepoint-using-workflow.aspx) you can find instruction how it can be done in SPD

Comment: To have done this kind of workflow in the past, I can tell you that is not reliable. It will fail a lot of times (for example if your Sharepoint is down or is rebooted or something similar). I now strongly recommend to my users to not create this kind of workflow.

Comment: And what's the alternative?

Comment: Nothing very satisfaisant. That could be a JavaScript script launched on a page each time someone is visiting a website that would check the dates, and that would launch a workflow. But it assumes that at least one person visits the website each day.
Another solution is a cron task for example, but it's independent from Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SharePoint Designer (SPD) workflow
Select your task list
Set it to run on Create
Click Next
In the Actions section add these three actions:
 - Add time to date
 - Pause until date
 - Send email

My example looks like this after the properties are set:

Add -7 days to Tasks:Due Date (Output to Variable: ReminderDate)
    then Pause until Variable: Reminder Date
    then Email this message    (you can hard code the address or use the assigned to... )

Notes for this very simple example:
 - If someone edits the task and sets a new due date, this workflow will still send the reminder based on the old date.
 - It does not check to see if the Due Date is at least two days in the future.

Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acb12dd2-d6a5-4b7e-b233-037558bfa2e5/start-workflow-x-days-before-expiry-date?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy